# Teamviewer black windows

Tags: kali-linux, teamviewer

I have recently dual booted my Win10 laptop (64 bit) with Kali Linux and installed Teamviewer but I can't interact with the menus in the first screen (Remote Control) and all popup windows are black except for input fields and buttons. Or at least I used to get that. Now all I get is a black error window and then the program shuts down. It also doesn't show up in the applications menu, so I can only run it by typing "teamviewer" in the console.

[image]

It feels like it needs reinstalling but I've tried so many times with so many different ways, that I can't find any others now.

Answer (score 1):

odd, maybe they are using wine (havn't checked), but in some older versions of wine this black window effect happened, there was a wine config option that could stop this happening.

will google for the prop...

Update:

Try winetricks ddr=gdi (or remove in-game videos).

https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=14410

also i found in one of my tomboy notes from 2012;

Just open regedit and added a key and a text value as below:

"xorg bug black area"

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\X11 Driver]
"ClientSideWithRender"="N"
```

Comment: when I try "winetricks ddr=gdi" it says winetricks command not found and when I try the regedit there is no X11 Driver in HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Wine